# Is PVC lumber strong enough to act as a barn door hardware shim?

Tags: structural, fastener, lumber

I am hanging a barn door inside my house. I'm using a steel hardware set (rail, hangers to roll on the rail, bracket to mount the rail).  The door plus hardware will be a bit shy of 100lb.  The rail will be about 90" long (opening about 42").

I'll use a 1x4 between the rail and the wall, secured to the wall studs with about 5 lag screws at irregular intervals up to 20" or so; the rail will be secured to the 1x4 with 6 stainless-steel supports (supplied with the hardware kit) at regular ~16" spacing.

Is PVC lumber suitable for this ?   I think the main issue would be the loading on the fasteners which secure the 1x4 to the wall studs (1/4" lag bolts) and which secure the rail to the 1x4 (#10 or #13 wood screws); the loading would be "twisting", pulling sideways and downwards on the fasteners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, synthetic boards outperform wood on every metric at room temperature.  Your door is not particularly heavy, about 25lb/foot, or more likely ~50-100lb variable load on each of 2 rollers.  Note that you should not screw deeper than 1.25" into a wall that you don't know the contents of, and 1" is safer.

Personally, I'd use an excessive amount of screws, not necessarily something so big I'd call it a lag bolt, to secure the 1x4 to the wall.  2 or 3 screws per stud on 16" studs should be nicely excessive with common #10 wood screws and the general 80lb per screw rule.  Not difficult to countersink for a flush surface either.  As far as securing the rail to the mounting board, again it's probably cheaper to do something excessive than calculate what is necessary.  You don't need to hit studs.  Thats the point of the mounting board.  Honestly 16" spacing is probably fine although doubling fasteners on the ends and or using a washer to reduce the amount the rail can "torque" on the screws may be a good idea if the rail is a softer metal like aluminum.

When you're worried about torque and you don't know engineering calculations, just look at the side view of the object and consider what the longest lever it has available to pull on the fastener is, and consider how to either reduce it or give the fastener a lever to use against it.  That said, What will it cost you to put a screw every 6-8" and simply guarantee an excessively strong, durable mounting?

Edit:  Based on Isherwood's comment, I did a bit more research, and it appears the product you are asking about is not what I would call synthetic lumber as it is not meant to replace lumber in function.  The product I believe you're asking about is "trim", meaning it is meant only to meet or exceed the structural properties of trim in its use case.  It appears the correct terminology for what I was referring to is Structural Plastic Lumber or Structural Composite Lumber.

That said I thoroughly examined the [product in question](https://www.homedepot.ca/product/veranda-1-inch-x-4-inch-x-12-feet-pvc-trim-board-white/1000760288) and it does appear to be more than adequate for your use case.  It is indeed a type of foam, although rather than "glorified", it might be better to use the term "extremely strong" so that people get a good picture of what it is compared to what most people think of when they hear "foam".  It is not as rigid as equal dimension wood, but with 20" studs, your maximum lever length to use against it is 10" against two fixed points.  It takes a tremendous amount of force to produce any significant twisting deflection over 20" of the product, and fighting two levers half as long should be roughly 4x as difficult.  Add to this that once fixed in two points, the product must stretch to bend between them.  Once screwed securely to studs, this product will be adequately rigid, especially given the added rigidity provided by the necessarily C shaped rail.  The one caveat I see is that in your comments you reveal you don't believe the wall to be straight.  Easy enough to check, but if it's more than 1/8"-1/4" deflection over 4f, I would have reservation about using the product without appropriate shims to straighten it, even with the rail providing tremendous rigidity.  That said, it is not particularly hard to deform a wood 1/4 that much over that length either.  Two screws per stud should easily provide enough force.  I would regard the straightness of the wall as a separate problem to be measured and evaluated.

The product is extremely resistant to compression, no issues there.

Screw pullout is very respectable even with normal wood screws and no pre drilling.  With an appropriately chosen wide thread screw, pullout strength will be fine although personally rather than a single screw in the center every 16" as your product seems to be made for, I'd consider using two screws countersunk and spaced vertically from eachother to give the screws more leverage against railing twist.  In honesty the 16" spacing is probably carefully calculated to be more than adequate, but you're doing the work yourself, so for a one time additional labor cost of 0$ and the low cost of some extra screws and possibly a countersink that you can use for many projects to come, I tend to fairly often double up fasteners.  The "Normal" downward forces that the door places on the railing will produce a very spread out and limited "tilting" or "twisting" force, compressing against the backing and pulling against the fasteners.  If one day your kids are horsing around and bodycheck the door or some such, using the entire length of the door as a lever against the railing, you may be glad you used extra mounting precautions.  The best you can do is to mount it securely enough that the method of failure is either deformation of the rail or unmounting of the door.

Screw bend test was fine as well.  I was able to bend the shaft of a 3" screw protruding two inches from the product without damage to the hole that would decrease holding strength.  The amount of effort it took to mess up the hole by repeatedly "wiggling" the screw was quite large and repetitive.

As fall as your acoustic board, it's compressive strength is measured with a janka test, which is typical for wood and I was not able to find a test for drywall done in the same way.  That said,  1/2" drywall is rated for 350PSI compressive and your acoustic product passes a 230lb Janka test.  I didn't have $75.00 to get a copy of ASTM D1037, but the original janka test is force applied to a steel ball with cross sectional area of 1 cm squared, or 0.155 inches square.  Assuming the same sized ball is used, this would equate to 1483 PSI, so it seems likely your product outperforms drywall in compressive strength.  Note that the 350PSI for drywall refers to the maximum force that will not produce a dent, whereas the Janka test refers to the force required to embed a steel ball to half it's diameter.

It's also worth noting a few advantages this particular synthetic has over wood.  It's impervious to moisture damage without additional treatment, extremely resistant to splitting, has excellent properties for its weight(not relevant in your case).  It cannot compare in rigidity due to the nature of foam and flexibility of PVC, but between your extremely rigid wall and extremely rigid rail, this should not be an issue.

This could be further evaluated with side view dimensions of the rail, knowledge of what material it is and vertical spacing of existing screw holes.  Note that the door moves, so it is wise to calculate based on much higher numbers than the static 100lb weight of the door, as one day it may be "slammed".

Comment: Yes, the point of the 1x4 is to interface the even spacing of the rail mounts with the un-eveness of the studs I'm dealing with.  Also to get the spacing between door face and trim right.

Comment: I like the suggestion to use multiple smaller screws per stud, and counter-sinking.  The rail mounts to the 1x4 with 6 nice brackets that came with the hardware kit, each with a hole sized for a #12 screw, so I'm stuck with that.  I did not know about a "general 80lb per screw" rule, but that should allow for all the weigh of the door plus hardware kit all coming down on one screw.   And the brackets have large flat flanges where they'll fit against the 1x4.

Comment: One complication is that there is not only a piece of drywall between the 1x4 and the studs, but an add'l 1/2" piece of "sound board" (a weak fibrous material) - so 1" total, thereby increasing that lever arm you're talking about.   I suppose I could cut a round fillet out of the soundbard+drywall and put a wood or metal spacer on the screws.   Do you think I need consider that ?

Comment: I'm just playing a bit of Dota, but I'll draw up a picture and consider it.  The additional soft layers are often not a problem provided screws are placed well and they cannot be compressed, and often their compression strength, at least for drywall is very decent.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  If it helps, I believe this is the sound-board material: https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/3f/3f27ed75-dc9c-490c-9bb1-a233315dd6e0.pdf

Comment: "Synthetic lumber" isn't a thing. It's a broad and nebulous category of things. In my experience, PVC boards are soft and floppy and in no way suited to anything structural.

Comment: @Isherwood my bad with the terminology problem.  I added an evaluation of what appears to be the product in question, which does indeed appear to be more than adequate for this particular purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your expanded answer.    You convinced me, and based on effort alone, you deserve the credit (sorry @isherwood but thanks to you too).   I decided to go with oak instead, not so much because of the misgivings isherwood raised about strength as because of the non-flatness of the wall issue; I will carefully check that, but I think the much greater stiffness of the oak will make it easier to get it right

Comment: Thanks much too for the carteful analysis of the issue of those materials in between the 1x4 and the studs.

Comment: Happy to help.  Material evaluation is always fun.  Isherwood was right to mention, as I was indeed comparing to the wrong product.

Comment: Finally ... I did use two screws - big #14 x 4" ones - on each stud to which I attached the oak 1x4.   Note that where the opening is, it goes all the way to the ceiling, a foot or so above where the rail runs.   Thus I'll be adding a small header there (with some decorative element between it and the ceiling).   So in that area the 1x4 will have virtually continuous support.

Comment: As far as doubling up on the connections of the rail to the 1x4, that's a non-starter.  I used this beautifully engineered hardware kit (see next comment for URL) which provides 6 brackets to mount the rail.   They each have one screw hole, and it'd be awkward to add a second screw.    However, I used a 1-1/4" stainless #12 screw, and it seems very strong; it made me glad I decided to use the oak, because the screw is IN there.    The 1-1/4" means the screw protrudes 1/4" past the back of the 1x4, so I'm getting the full strength (the tapering of the threads is beyond the rear of the 1x4).

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01G4T8U3Y/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Answer (score 2):

No. **PVC lumber is decorative only.** It's very soft and limber (being quite porous inside) and will leave you with sagging structures and open joints. Even most PVC railings and fences either have metal or reinforced plastic structures inside, and they're usually solid-wall tubing, quite unlike boards.

Now, if it's fiberglass or some other structurally-capable material that happens to be *coated* with PVC, sure. But PVC alone? Nope. No way.

**However...**, if you use bolts that are stiff enough to carry the load *themselves*, you're probably going to be fine. Don't count on PVC (glorified foam) to handle any bending stress.

Comment: Well, of course it's going to be in a vertical orientation (3.5" dimension vertical, 3/4" dimension sticking out from wall).   And the maximum distance from screws holding to 1x4 to wall studs and ones holding rail to 1x4 will be about 4" (and most closer than that).   But there's still that 1" of soundboard+drywall between the studs and the rail-mounting brackets, and another 3/4" of the 1x4s thickness, and you're saying I can't rely on the PVC 1x4 to provide any support - so I have to just assume the fasteners are cantilevered 1-3/4" out from the studs ?

Comment: Maybe better to just use an oak 1x4.   My motivation for the PVC was simply that I don't want this to look like wood (more like a bulge in the drywall), and it's slightly cheaper.   Plus the wall may not be totally flat along the 90" span, and the oak is more likely to stay flat (and not bend to conform to waviness in the wall).

Comment: "... so I have to just assume the fasteners are cantilevered 1-3/4" out from the studs?" That's basically it. PVC extrusions like that are really soft. The holes will just deform if the bolts aren't stiff enough to carry the load, especially where movement is involved. To your second comment... I'd just upsize the bolts. Then you're not relying on the PVC to carry anything and are probably fine. Be sure to pilot properly into the framing.

Comment: I decided to use an oak 1x4, for reasons in my previous comment (in addition to your reservations about the PVC).